# Сохранение состояние setResult(RESULT_OK) после пересоздания активити

Tags: android, activity

Есть два активити: из первого открываем второе методом `startActivityForResult`, а на втором по определенному событию выставляем результат `RESULT_OK`. Но после поворота экрана на второй активити `RESULT_OK` сбрасывается. Если ли какой то способ сохранить это состояние инструментами андроид? Решение использовать во второй активити переменную `boolean isResultOK` и сохранять ее через механизм `onSaveInstanceState`, а `setResult(RESULT_OK)`  вызывает уже в onDestroy работает, но это выглядит костыльно

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation" а если эту штуку в манифесте у активити прописать?

Comment: Да, отличная идея, но в своем проекте я уже заложился на пересоздание активити при повороте, поэтому добавлять этот атрибут уже не могу (

Answer (score 3):

В Вашем случае сработает `onSaveInstanceState`, сохраните result.
Восстановите его в `onRestoreInstanceState` как вы и написали.

Помним, что onSaveInstanceState не вызовется, если всё пройдет в штатном порядке. Делать дополнительную проверку с помощью `boolean isResultOK` может быть излишним.